# javascript automate printing with google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

need to make Google Chrome print a page automatically.
I have a page that is opened when the user clicks my apps print button
The page opens, the chrome preview window opens
What i want to do is somehow - select the right printer - the user can specify what that is elsewhere in my app under settings, then print the page to that printer and then close the windows. This should happen so quick that when the user presses print the printer starts printing.
I need a solution to do this from java-script within a client app built in a webpage.
What are the solutions can this be done.
Thanks all