# remove message select printer and automatically print the document with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I'm working in a process of printing documents and found an alternative that is using javascript.

The code is:

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printpage()
{
   window.print();
   window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="printpage()">
<embed src="pdfhere.pdf"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If I create a html page and open it with internet explorer, I sent a message to select the printer and print the document.
**What I want to do is automatically print the document without displaying that message**
thanks for your help.

Comment: what if they don't have a printer and want to print to say a microsoft document or something of that nature

Comment: they have a printer connected all the time, so I need to remove that printer selection message @Ronnie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891259/can-i-have-javascript-select-printer-to-use seems only IE based though

Comment: another for IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window

Comment: and for chrome, granted chrome has to start with certain params: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742130/javascript-automate-printing-with-google-chrome

Answer (score 2):

You can't skip the browser print dialog. This is provided by your browser/OS.

`window.print()` is the best you can do.

Comment: I haven't posibility to remove the message?

Comment: No, you can't skip the print dialog.